# Android parsefile url is changing to http

Tags: android, nginx, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

When I upload a `ParseFile` the link is changed to http for some reason. And because of this during the download the link goes to nginx which does a 301 redirect to `https`. This results in a "moved permanently" exception in the Android code and the download fails. My upload code is below.

```
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("image.jpg", data);

file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d(tag, "Successfully uploaded image file to: " + file.getUrl());
        }
    }
}
```

The `Log.d` prints out this line,

```
Successfully uploaded image file to: http://<server_addr>/parse/files/<app_id>/b55beba96cab60cecea084365d1f2c3e_image.jpg
```

Here is my initialization code for parse.

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("<app_id>")
                .server("https://<server_addr>/parse/")
                .build());
```

As you can see `https` is clearly specified in the initialization code but the ParseFile url is `http`. So I am not sure what to do to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to set `parseServerURL` variable when initializing the parse-server. Setting that as a `https` url fixed everything.